# Поиск неуникальных значений в диапазоне данных

Tags: excel, vba

Пытаюсь найти не уникальные значения в стобце и пометить их. Нашел "условное форматирование -> правила выделения ячеек-> повторяющиеся значения"

На основе этого функционала cгенерировал макрос. Подскажите, как изменить макрос так, чтобы с указанную ячейку строки дописать комментарий о том, что информация дублируется.
Не смог понять логику работы этого макроса.

```
Sub Tst()

    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues         
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1        
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Непонятна постановка задачи. Нужно изменить фон тех ячеек, значение которых встречается в столбце только один раз? я понял именно так. И непонятна фраза _изменить макрос так, чтобы с указанную ячейку строки дописать комментарий_ - мало того, что не по-русски, так ещё и, как мне кажется, есть намерение изменить данные в ячейке... после чего, кстати, она теоретически может стать дубликатом.

Comment: Изменил вопрос(нужны дубли), плохо написал. Надо найти дубликаты и в соседней ячейке написать комментарий. Хотел доработать созданный макрос, но не понял как

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как изменить макрос... Надо найти дубликаты и в соседней ячейке написать комментарий

Тут не дорабатывать надо, а менять подход. Сначала залить условным форматированием, потом пытаться по этому форматированию определить дубли...

Проще. По значениям ходим... и находим :)

Работа с объектами листа медленная, поэтому обрабатывать лучше в памяти.

Проверяем значения столбца D. В столбец E записываем номера строк найденных дублей.

```
Sub Tst()
Dim Ar()
Dim lRws As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row ' последняя заполненная ячейка
        Ar = .Range("D1:D" & lRws).Value ' значения в массив
        ReDim Preserve Ar(1 To lRws, 1 To 2) ' расширяем размерность для комментариев

            For i = 1 To lRws - 1 ' цикл по проверяемым значениям
                If Ar(i, 1) <> Empty Then ' значение есть
                    For k = i + 1 To lRws ' цикл по сравниваемым значениям
                        If Ar(i, 1) = Ar(k, 1) Then ' нашли дубль
                            ' записываем комментарий - номера строк с дублями
                            Ar(i, 2) = Ar(i, 2) & "/" & k
                            Ar(k, 2) = Ar(k, 2) & "/" & i
                        End If
                    Next k
                End If
            Next i

            .Range("D1:E" & lRws).Value = Ar ' выгрузка на лист
        End With
    End Sub
```

---

Код ниже отметит повторы значений:

```
Sub SearchOfTakes()
Dim rRng As Range, c As Range
Dim oDict As Object
Dim lRws As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row ' последняя заполненная ячейка
        Set rRng = .Range("D1:D" & lRws) ' диапазон в переменную
        Set oDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") ' словарь

        For Each c In rRng ' цикл по ячейкам диапазона
            If c.Value <> "" Then ' значение есть
                If oDict.exists(c.Value) Then ' если значение было раньше
                    c.Offset(, 1) = "дубль" ' отмечаем его
                Else ' значение первый раз в диапазоне
                    Set oDict(c.Value) = c ' в словарь
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Может быть... По задаче непонятно. Вдруг критично?

Comment: Зачем удалять? Ведь нужная информация...

Comment: Добавьте ответ с дополнениями. так будет правильнее.

Answer (score 1):

Выдели диапазон (или всю колонку). Открой "Условное форматирование". Выбери условие "Формула". В поле условия введи

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A:A;A1)=1;ЛОЖЬ;ИСТИНА)
```

Замени A:A на адрес колонки (скажем, в твоём случае это будет D:D) или диапазона (например D1:D58). Замени A1 на адрес самой верхней левой ячейки диапазона (скажем, это будет D1). Установи требуемый формат (например, красный фон). Нажми ОК.

В терминах VBA это будет

```
Range("D:D").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.Add _
    Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(D:D;D1)=1;ЛОЖЬ;ИСТИНА)"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = vbRed
```

Comment: Достаточно: *=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A:A;A1)=1* *Excel* дальше сам  разберется )